# Serializing object with fields depending on other field

Tags: java, serialization, coding-style, refactoring

Let's assume I have a class with given structure:

```
class Problem {
  private String longString;
  private String firstHalf;
  private String secondHalf;
}
```

**firstHalf** and **secondHalf** are computed from **longString** and are used extensively in my application, however I don't want to serialize them. Now, in order for serialization of this object to work, I need a setter for **longString**. I want to protect invariants that **firstHalf** and **secondHalf** are computed from **longString**, exist only when **longString** exists and that value passed to **longString** is correct in a sense that there can be computed first and second half. My current solution is to have the setter for **longString** written like this:

```
public void setLongString(String value) {
  this.longString=value;
  this.firstHalf=computeFirstHalf(value);
  this.secondHalf=computeSecondHalf(value);
}
```

This code also implies tight correlation between **longString** and first and second half.

However, one thing that bugs me is the fact, that method **setLongString** does in fact three things and its name doesn't reflect its true behaviour.

Is there a way to code this better?

Edit 1:
I'm using Jackson to json serializer and I have getters for first and second half, annotated with @JsonIgnore.

I want to express the tight coupling between **longString** and it's halves.

Comment: You're doing serialization by standard java serialization mechanism or by custom serializer?

Comment: If you want to serialize an object, but do not want specific fields serialized within the object, mark those fields as transient `transient String something = "";' In addition, you should really make all of your fields private anyway and provide proper getter/setter methods. You could then, in your set methods, check if a fields has already been set and not reset the value, or any other business logic that makes sense..which is a benefit of Object Oriented design

Comment: I'm using Jackson to json serializer. My fields are private and I have getters (ignored by Jackson) for them, I will edit my question to show that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Problem {
  private String longString;
  private String firstHalf;
  private String secondHalf;

  //Getters of All Variables
    ......
    ......
    ......

  // Setters of All Variables.

  public void setLongString(String longString){
     this.longString = longString;
     }

  // public but no Arguments so that user won't be able to set this Explicitly but 
  //make a call Outside of the Class to set Only and only if longString is there.

  public void setFirstHalf(){   
       if(this.longString == null)
            throw new Exception("Long String is Not Set.");
       this.firstHalf = this.computeFirstHalf(this.longString);
   }

     // public but no Arguments so that user won't be able to Set Explicitly but 
    //make a call Outside of the Class to set Only and only if longString is there.

   public void setSecondHalf(){  
       if(this.longString == null)
            throw new Exception("Long String is Not Set.");
       this.secondHalf = this.computeSecondHalf(this.longString);
   }
//private method not Accessible outside of Class
   private String computeFirstHalf(final String value){ 
     //Your Logical Code. 
    }
 //private method not Accessible outside of Class
   private String computeSecondHalf(final String value){ 
        //Your Logical Code.
}
```

Comment: looks good when we do not need to be java-beans-compliant. Proposed solution is not compliant (set* methods without parameter).

Some frameworks are able to live with such customization (for jackson we can annotate compute*Half with @JsonProperty

Answer (score 1):

firstHalf and secondHalf computations could be done lazily (i.e. using getters)

```
public void getFirstHalf() {
    if (this.longString != null) {
        this.firstHalf = computeFirstHalf(longString);
    }
    return this.firstHalf;
}
```

same can be followed for second half.

Comment: looks good if all values of longString are valid to compute firstHalf/secondHalf. If this is not the case, I prefer to compute halfes it setLong string. That way we protect class invariant. If longString is not good we fail at once, rather that during getFirstHalf call.